# Dateformat: format pattern based on date value

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I have date `2013/10/09 00:00:00- 10908- 11`. And I want to know the date format pattern for it. And how to guess date format pattern based on date.

Thanks

Comment: What is `10908- 11` part?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the brute force approach to find a solution for your query. On searching I landed on a code which could give you a heads up on the approach

```
private static final Map<String, String> DATE_FORMAT_REGEXPS = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("^\\d{8}$", "yyyyMMdd");
    put("^\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}$", "dd-MM-yyyy");
    put("^\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}$", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    put("^\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}$", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    put("^\\d{4}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}$", "yyyy/MM/dd");
    put("^\\d{1,2}\\s[a-z]{3}\\s\\d{4}$", "dd MMM yyyy");
    put("^\\d{1,2}\\s[a-z]{4,}\\s\\d{4}$", "dd MMMM yyyy");
    put("^\\d{12}$", "yyyyMMddHHmm");
    put("^\\d{8}\\s\\d{4}$", "yyyyMMdd HHmm");
    put("^\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}$", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    put("^\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}$", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    put("^\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}$", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    put("^\\d{4}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}$", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    put("^\\d{1,2}\\s[a-z]{3}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}$", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
    put("^\\d{1,2}\\s[a-z]{4,}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}$", "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm");
    put("^\\d{14}$", "yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    put("^\\d{8}\\s\\d{6}$", "yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
    put("^\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    put("^\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    put("^\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    put("^\\d{4}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    put("^\\d{1,2}\\s[a-z]{3}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    put("^\\d{1,2}\\s[a-z]{4,}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$", "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}};

/**
 * Determine SimpleDateFormat pattern matching with the given date string. Returns null if
 * format is unknown. You can simply extend DateUtil with more formats if needed.
 * @param dateString The date string to determine the SimpleDateFormat pattern for.
 * @return The matching SimpleDateFormat pattern, or null if format is unknown.
 * @see SimpleDateFormat
 */
public static String determineDateFormat(String dateString) {
    for (String regexp : DATE_FORMAT_REGEXPS.keySet()) {
        if (dateString.toLowerCase().matches(regexp)) {
            return DATE_FORMAT_REGEXPS.get(regexp);
        }
    }
    return null; // Unknown format.
}
```

This is code snippet from the blog [DateUtil](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/09/dateutil.html).
Hope this turns out to be useful for you.

Comment: If you found the answer to your query in this, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Jaykob: use this

'put("^\\d{1,2}.\\d{1,2}.\\d{4}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}$", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");'

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.text.ParseException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NewClass {

    private static final String[] formats = { 
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",        "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", 
                "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", 
                "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ",     "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", 
                "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss",        "yyyyMMdd", };

        /*
         * @param args
         */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String yyyyMMdd = "20110917";   
        parse(yyyyMMdd);
    }

    public static void parse(String d) {
        if (d != null) {
            for (String parse : formats) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(parse);
                try {
                    sdf.parse(d);
                    System.out.println("Printing the value of " + parse);
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```